# I want to connect Outlook Calendar with React Native app and sync functionality.Is there any library or api which can help me?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, outlook, outlook-calendar

I'm trying to develop an app in which I want to integrate outlook calendar.And I want to create events and any changes which I will make outlook calendar it will be automatically sync
within the app.Kindly guide me if you have ever done this before.Regards

Answer (score 3):

**Right now Outlook Calendar is not available for particular react-native**, but It's SDK is available for native (Android/iOS). you can integrate it in native Apps by using Outlook Calendar's api and SDK
[here's a link for Outlook Calendar's api and SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/get-started)

**There's one way to integrate Outlook Calendar:**

> You just need to implement the sdk and api in react-native android side then after you need to create a bridge between android and react-native (same for iOS)

**Similiar Libraries which can be used Alternatively :**
[react-native-calendar-events](https://github.com/wmcmahan/react-native-calendar-events)
[react-native-big-calendar](https://github.com/llotheo/react-native-big-calendar)

Answer (score 1):

You should use Outlook Calendar API to interact with all calendar related events :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/calendar?view=graph-rest-1.0

I recommend to integrate it in your backend to have the possibility to control your data and add some controller jobs (if your app have backend)